# HTML5 Application Cache Error Event Detail

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, application-cache

I have an HTML5 offline app and on occasion users have cache errors which I handle with the event listener and display a generic error message.

In order to help debug these I'd like to also display and log the error details (as seen in the Chrome console), such as a failed get. I have not yet found a way to get the details through Javascript. Is this currently possible?

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this:

```
var appCache = window.applicationCache;
    function handleCacheError(e){
          console.log(e);
    }
    appCache.addEventListener('error', handleCacheError, false);
```

And then you should have the error logged to the Chrome console on error.

Comment: The event parameter `e` does not contain the actual cause of the error which is what I'm trying to get (eg. GET failed on which file?)